# Загрузка активити в фоне

Tags: android, activity, android-intent

Задача в следующем. Есть два активити А и Б. из активити А мы переходим в активити Б по нажатию кнопки, но так как в активити Б тяжелая графика с логикой, пользователь около 5 секунд видит черный экран, что не очень хорошо. Задача в следующем. Как прописать логику открытия активити Б? Как пример, при нажатии на кнопку в фоне начать загрузку активити Б, в то время как в активити А проигрывается некая анимация. Вернуть состояние загрузки активити Б можно через коллбэк.

Comment: Скорей всего никак. Предполагается, что [Активити](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities) это то, что видит пользователь на экране. Если нужно делать что-то в фоне, то используйте [Сервисы](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services).

Comment: В конце мысль в верном направлении, но делать это нужно в самой активити Б. Пусть она изначально отображает что-то лёгкое (ту же анимацию к примеру) или UI без данных (плейсхолдеры), а загрузку всего добра выполнить в фоне и обновить UI по завершению или обновлять по мере загрузки.

Comment: А что если два активити переписать на фрагменты? Допустим есть активити, у которого два фрагмента, А и Б. из фрагмента А мы отправляем событие в главное активити, который начинает загружать фрагмент Б и отображает его, когда фрагмент Б закончил обработку. Активити открывает сам андроид и может открыто только одно и в фоне его никак не заставить загружаться, когда во фрагментах мы сами решаем когда отображаться, или есть подводные в этом методе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема появления черного экрана было в добавлении флагов в интент для стирания всего стека активити. Решение оказалось на порядок проще. Получается что активных активити нет, поэтому андроид показывает черный экран.

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
// homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(homeIntent);
this.finish();
```